# How to obtain github "short" username at the command line?

Tags: git, bash, github, terminal, environment-variables

So if..

```
$ git config user.name
↳ Alex Gray              # OK (my name)
$ git config user.email
↳ alex@mrgray.com        # OK (my email).
```

and..

```
GithubUserForProject() {  # in pwd
    ORIGIN=$(git config --get remote.origin.url) && echo $ORIGIN
    OWNER=${ORIGIN%/*}     && echo $OWNER  # trim URL tail
    OWNER=${OWNER#*.com/}  && echo $OWNER  # trim URL head
    OWNER=${OWNER#*:}      && echo $OWNER  # trim ssh URL head
}

$ cd /local/git/MyGitHubRepo && GithubUserForProject
↓ git@github.com:mralexgray/MyGitHubRepo.git
↓ git@github.com:mralexgray
↳ mralexgray            # OK (my username, but skanky way of finding it)
```

but...

```
$ cd /local/git/SomeGuysProject && GithubUserForProject
↓ git://github.com/someguy/SomeGuysProject.git
↓ git://github.com/someguy
↳ someguy              # WRONG! (cloned repo's user!)
```

So, how **can** I determine my github "short username" programmatically, either from the `env`ironment, a github API request, etc., *or otherwise* (via a script or terminal session?

Comment: If you mean just your own account name, and not one that varies based on which clone you're working in, why not just hard-code it? It's not going to change. If it's something you're trying to derive from git remotes, git has no way of knowing which remotes are 'yours' or 'canonical'. To make an API call to github you'd have to supply user credentials, so you might as well just supply yourself the username and not bother with the call. Perhaps `export GITHUB_USERNAME='mralexgray'` and be done with it? Somehow, I feel I've misunderstood your problem.

Comment: No, you've got it, and your solution IS how I have traditionally managed this variable.. But I find it kind of weird that this value is so decoupled from "the workflow", and thought there must be some way of getting at it that I hadn't considered.

Comment: Weird? It seems sensible to me. git should talk to all remotes as though they're the same - why should it be able to figure out your github account name? You could include your username as a comment in your `~/.ssh/config` github stanza and parse that out. At least that's sort of an appropriate place to record it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it silly that *such an inane question* go so glaringly unsolved... so for lack of knowing how to cleverly parse strings in bash without resorting to the one `SED` combo I know by heart, and......

`security find-internet-password -s github.com | grep acct | sed 's/"acct"<blob>="//g' | sed 's/"//g'`

*ét voila....*

`mralexgray`

This may depend on having the Github mac client installed... and yet again... *it might not*.

Comment: You can simplify that command to `security find-internet-password -s github.com | grep acct | sed 's/^.*="\(.*\)".*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to agree with the commenters: how would Bash know your username, unless you tell it?

You could test with `git push` to know if it is "your" repo, but even that will fail if your SSH keys aren't properly set. In short, you should just set it in `~/.bash_profile` or something and be done with it.